# iOS app use Facebook app credential

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, fbconnect

I have installed Facebook app on my device. I have remove Facebook login and password from device settings, but Facebook app still has itself credentials.

I try to use this code:

```
NSString *accessToken = [[FBSession.activeSession accessTokenData] accessToken];
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];

[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *err) {
}];
```

But accessToken is nil. How can use Facebook app credential without using web view authorization. Because there is an account in Facebook app and seems I can use it, but how can access current access token or session?

So alpo there are 3 ways to login to app:

1. Using device setting for facebbok
2. Using web view authorization
3. Using oficial Facebook app credentials - about which I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

I handled the same by creating a singleton class.
And whenever I used the facebook functionality I called the following class

```
[self.classObj facebookLogin:self];

- (void)facebookLogin:(id)delegate {

  sharedFacebookHelper.delegate = delegate;

  if (!sharedFacebookHelper.session.isOpen) {
    // Create a new, logged out session.


    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"set your permissions here",nil];


    sharedFacebookHelper.session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];

///////////////////////////////////

  NSString *accessToken =  [sharedFacebookHelper.session.accessTokenData accessToken];

//////////////////////////////////////




    [FBSession setActiveSession:sharedFacebookHelper.session];

//  Popup code here..

//  And whatever code for your facebook functionality here

}else {

//We already the session data so go ahead the whatever facebook functionality we need

}
```

Appdelegate Code :

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {


[[MyFacebookHelperClassName sharedFacebookHelper] handleBecomeActive];

}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {


return [[MyFacebookHelperClassName sharedFacebookHelper] handleOpenURL:url forSourceApplication:sourceApplication];
 }



- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

 [[MyFacebookHelperClassName sharedFacebookHelper] closeSession];

}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but how can I get token and credential from facebook app. NSString *accessToken = [[FBSession.activeSession accessTokenData] accessToken]; return to me null

Comment: check the updated code between ///////////////////////////////////

  NSString *accessToken =  [sharedFacebookHelper.session.accessTokenData accessToken];

//////////////////////////////////////

Comment: do you think it will use official facebook app credentials?

Comment: Please read the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios. You have essentially asked the same question 3 times on this forum without reading the docs themselves.